# Remote indicator light for alarm panel when armed

Tags: circuit-design, solid-state-relay

I have an security alarm panel that I would like to have an indicator light turn on when the system is armed. From what I can see there are no remote contacts or anything to do this from the alarm panel, so here is my idea. I would like to power a relay from the led that shows the system is armed. Is there a low power ssr that I could hook up to the led solder points or an easy circuit with a transistor that would accomplish this. Or am off my rocker. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: in theory, LED takes more than 10 mA to power up which you might be able to use to turn on a transistor that drives a relay

Comment: A solid state relay has an LED internally, so it will probably work fine if you hook it up to the status LED pins. It will also provide isolation, so you don't accidentally create a ground loop or something. You may not be able to power the status LED and SSR at the same time.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest a appropriate part number for an ssr that would switch 12 volt 1 amp load.

Comment: Opening up the control panel to modify if probably trips the sabotage alarm and erases the firmware or settings.

Comment: Nope, done it already, all is fine.

Comment: If LED is 10 mA and load is 1A you have a current gain 100 approx which is not practical for a saturated BJT but thousands of  FETS can handle that easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track! But -- the security system will have a current limiting resistor in series with the LED, and the SSR will have it's own current limiting resistor.  If you try to connect the SSR where the LED connects, those two resistors may add up to too much resistance to operate the SSR. Also, the LED may stop working!

You need to understand how the LED is powered. It will probably have a resistor in series (i.e. connected to one pin of the LED). Call that pin 1. Use a voltmeter to probe from the other LED pin (pin 2) to the far end of the resistor, measuring voltage and polarity with the system armed and disarmed.

Now just get an SSR that activates on that voltage, and preferably one that doesn't take more than a few milliamps. Connect it up. The built-in LED should keep working.